# Find all 'big' cycles in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am unfamiliar with graph theory and hope to get answers here.
My goal is to find all 'big' cycles in an undirected graph. A 'big' cycle is a cycle that is not a part of another cycle. (Compare with [Find cycles in graphs which do not contain other cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250693/find-cycles-in-graphs-which-do-not-contain-other-cycles)) For example, in contrast with chordless cycles (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022662/find-all-chordless-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph), a 'big' cycle here is $0$-$1$-$2$-$3$-$4$-$0$.

One idea based on the 'chordless cycles' algorithm is to find all the 'chordless' cycles first, then merge two cycles if they share a common edge. Another idea is to find all the cycles and exclude those containing sub-cycles. However, these two approaches are inefficient. I believe there are better solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but it seems like if you had an efficient algorithm, you'd be able to efficiently find Hamiltonian cycles, a well-known NP-complete problem. So you're probably out of luck, in the general case at least.

Comment: Is a "big" cycle the same as a maximal cycle?